# Automate converting text to rows and columns (Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets, split

I'm trying to convert order form data submitted from a Squarespace website from the following format to a table with 4 columns:

Store,Item,Quantity,Details;Store2,Item2,Quantity2,Details2; (etc...)

Commas separate columns while semi-colons separate rows.
All the methods I've tried so far have been successful in splitting the data into the desired form, but the problem occurs when new data is added. When the form is submitted, it creates a new row in the next available empty row. I can't seem to find a way to automate the process without receiving cyclical dependency errors, since each order can have any amount of item entries.

Example spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZEWtmMiWO0Us76Z7o7GB7Salw1Rl_-1PhK6GzeOD0GM/edit?usp=sharing

The above example splits the data as desired. I cannot figure out how to make it work with the data added as a new row. I would also like to continue using sheets for its cloud functionality.

Any advice is appreciated, including entirely new ways of processing the data, whether with a script, a different remotely accessible order processing app compatible with Squarespace forms, or natively within Sheets.

Answer (score 2):

- You want to achieve the following conversion.

  [image]

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(split(A4,";")),","))
```

- In this formula, the cell "A4" has the input value.
- You have already used the formula of `=TRANSPOSE(split(A10,";"))`. In this answer, I used this.

  - For `TRANSPOSE(split(A10,";"))`, the value is splitted with `,` using `SPLIT` and `ARRAYFORMULA`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Sample script:

When you want to use Google Apps Script, you can also use the following script.

```
function myFunction(value) {
  const values = value.split(";");
  return values.splice(0, values.length - 1).map(e => e.split(",").map(f => isNaN(f) ? f : Number(f)));
}
```

- In this case, please copy and paste the script to the script editor, and put the custom function of `=myFunction(A4)` to a cell.

  - The same result with above formula can be obtained.

#### References:

- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Your solution works but requires the function/formula to be dragged down in order to work. This is an issue because the data is added as a new row. So what will happen is that when the data is added, it will go below the last row that the formulas are in, and thus there will be no formula applied to the new data. Is there a way to run a script that reprocesses the whole sheet every time it's run, or some other solution like that?

Comment: @kjoy Thank you for replying. I apologize for my incomplete answer for your goal. This is due to my poor skill. In order to correctly understand about your goal, I would like to confirm about it. 1. About `what will happen is that when the data is added`, how is the data added? It's a script? 2. Where cells are the data added? 3. You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No worries, thanks for the quick responses. The data is coming from a form on a Squarespace website. Upon form submission, it is added as a completely new row, with one cell containing the data separated by commas for columns and semi-colons for rows. Google Apps Script seems like a solution that would work, but I have a very limited understanding of it.

Comment: @kjoy Thank you for replying. About `The data is coming from a form on a Squarespace website.`, is the data put by a script or Google Form?

Comment: It is a Squarespace form linked to Google Sheets. Transfers the data to Sheets upon form submission. Effectively the same as a Google Form I suppose.

Comment: @kjoy Thank you for replying. For example, in the case of IFTTT, Sheets API is used instead of Google Form. So in your situation, I'm not sure about the method for putting the values to Spreadsheet. So I think that both patterns are required to be prepared. And also, can I ask you about the cell that the value is put? When the form is submitted, where cell (the column) is the value put to?

Comment: @kjoy And also, where cell (the column) do you want to put the converted value?

Comment: Thanks! The data is placed in the G column, in the first available (empty) row. I'm not sure either what exact method is used to place the values to the spreadsheet. All I know is that the Squarespace form transfers the data to the Google Sheet.

Comment: The converted values can go anywhere there is space for multiple rows and columns.

Comment: @kjoy Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `The converted values can go anywhere there is space for multiple rows and columns.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: For simplicity, the new values can start in I17

Comment: @kjoy Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `For simplicity, the new values can start in I17`. Because the data is put in a cell at the column "G". But the converted values are put to the several rows. In this case, when the data is continued to be appended, the last row is over than the column "G" due to the converted values. So can I ask you about the detail of it?